# Bind RichTextBox.Selection in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, richtextbox, selection

I have a RichTextBox in my MVVM program.
I would like to bind the RichTextBox.Selection property to my model.
To achieve this task, I've created a custom UserControl which contains a RichTextBox:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Resources.Controls.CustomRichTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextBox" SelectionChanged="RichTextBox_SelectionChanged"/>
</UserControl>
```

In my UserControl class:

```
// Selection property
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextSelectionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TextSelection", typeof(TextSelection),
    typeof(CustomRichTextBox));


[Browsable(true)]
[Category("TextSelection")]
[Description("TextSelection")]
[DefaultValue("null")]
public TextSelection TextSelection
{
    get { return (TextSelection)GetValue(TextSelectionProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextSelectionProperty, value); }
}
```

The usage is:

```
<ResourcesControls:CustomRichTextBox TextSelection="{Binding ModelTextSelection}"/>
```

And I have this property on my model:

```
private TextSelection _TextSelection;
public TextSelection TextSelection
{
    get { return _TextSelection; }
    set { _TextSelection = value; }
}
```

I would like to get the RichTextBox.Selection property in my model, but TextSelection is always null.
I know I'm missing the binding between the RichTextBox.Selection property and his model but I don't know how to do it.
I think I'm missing something but I can't find what.

Answer (score 0):

`RichTextBox.Selection` is not a `DependancyProperty` so you cannot bind to that.

But for your setup you just need to set the `BindingMode` as `TwoWay` on your `UserControl`  (ssuming your model property name is ModelTextSelection)

```
   <ResourcesControls:CustomRichTextBox TextSelection="{Binding ModelTextSelection, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

and in `SelectionChanged` method your need to update your `TextSelection` DependancyProperty with `RichTextBox.Selection`

```
    private void RichTextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

       TextSelection = richTextBox.Selection;

    }
```